# Fitting a linear function using Single Layer Neural Network in tensorflow

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I'm fitting a linear function $$y = x_1 + x_2$$ using a neural network with 1 hidden layer.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = tf.random.uniform(shape = [10000, 2], minval = -10, maxval=10)
Y = tf.math.reduce_sum(X, axis=-1)

random_init = tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05)

W1 = tf.Variable(random_init(shape=[2, 16], dtype=tf.float32))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([16], dtype=tf.float32))

W2 = tf.Variable(random_init(shape=[16, 1], dtype=tf.float32))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1], dtype=tf.float32))

optim = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)

for epoch in range(10):
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y)).shuffle(buffer_size=1000).batch(32)
  for x, y in dataset:
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      
      # Single hidden layer with ReLU non-linearity
      h1 = tf.math.maximum(x @ W1 + b1, 0)
      y_hat = h1 @ W2 + b2

      loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.pow(y - y_hat, 2))

    vars = [W1, b1, W2, b2]
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, vars)
    optim.apply_gradients(zip(grads, vars))
```

However, the model doesn't seem to fit the training data. Is there anything obviously wrong with the training setup?

[image]

Comment: Plot a graph of prediction vs. ground truth after training. What do you see?